# how to remove empty elements from nested list in R

Tags: r, nested-lists

I'm struggling with removing some elements from nested list. I'm close but don't know how to apply changes.

the list fragment is:

```
[[54]] [1] "\n"    ""    "World Health Organization ICTRP"

[[55]] [1] "\n"    "Sexes Eligible for Study:"    "All"
```

and I have `lapply(g, function(x) !(x == "" | x == "\n"))` then I get:

```
[[54]] [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

[[55]] [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

which are right indexes where I want the list to be shrunk (on false).
But don't know how to apply this on list. Something like `g <-  g[lapply(g, function(x) !(x == "" | x == "\n"))]` returns an error `invalid subscript type 'list'`. 
The solution is probably just there.

**EDIT**

I've found indirect solution - in a loop. For one [[]] element it is:

```
f <- g[[i]]
f <- f[lapply(f, function(x) !(x == "" | x == "\n"))==T]
f <- gsub("\n", "", f)
```

Comment: Can you give a small example code for us to try and give you some solution?

Comment: Fragment of list: g <- list(c("\n", "", "world"), c("\n", "All")).

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(g, function(x) x[x != "" & x != "\n"])`?

Comment: Yes. I knew that was close. Thanks!